# gstreamer buffers/bytes in queue2, appsrc

Tags: queue, gstreamer

Having read the gst-inspect-1.0 docs for queue2, appsrc,
I am confused. What is buffer and bytes (and time) ? Which one gets priority over the other.
Its possible to set  max-size-bytes, max-size-time and max-size-buffers on a pipeline.
But I don't get the right amount of buffering on the queue2.
Ex:
max-size-bytes=100 max-size-buffers=10
Would it mean total buffer size=1000, and at each burst of data arrival up to 10 bytes allowed?

Ideally I'd like to have a known amount of buffering at the appsrc or a queue2 right next to the appsrc.
The source is live-streamed mpeg2-TS. Could someone suggest a right setting for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all three max-size-bytes, max-size-time and max-size-buffers simultaneously. They all limit the amount of data that can be buffered internally in the queue. The first one to be hit blocks the buffering. For example, if your set max-size-buffer=100, max-size-time=10000000000 and max-size-bytes=20 you are:

1. Allowing a maximum of 100 buffers inside the queue
2. Allowing a maximum of 10 seconds worth of buffers inside the queue
3. Allowing a maximum of 20 bytes of buffer data inside the queue

As you can see, even though you have configured 100 buffers or 10 seconds, the 20 bytes will be hit first (likely on the first buffer), so you'll only be able to queue 1 buffer at a time (assuming that indeed the buffer data is larger that 20 bytes).

BTW, if you do not have a specific reason to use queue2, you should be using queue.

Finally, I don't understand how appsrc fits in your question.